# Music player to display the underlying folder structure

Tags: directory, music-player

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and am looking for a music player (banshee, rhythmbox or other) which can display the music files and folders as-is and not organized by artist/album/genre or some other field. I tried out banshee and rhythmbox and could not figure how to.

Btw, the music I have is not labeled and is just organized in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sonata`, GTK+ client for the Music Player Daemon (MPD), which can show you music in it library as it is stored in your computer folder-wise.

[image]

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPD) is how to install and configure `Sonata`

You can also  search in library using `Artist`,`Title`, `Album`,`Genre`,`Filename` or `Everything`

You can also use `guayadeque`:

Install `guayadeque` by `sudo apt-get install guayadeque`.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there a couple of terminal based players that can do this. Refer this similar question in Superuser.

https://superuser.com/questions/326471/is-there-a-folder-only-based-music-player-for-linux

Answer (score 0):

Use VLC. `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

Then go to "tools->"preferences". Under interface, there is a 'playlist' section at the bottom. Check 'Display playlist tree' then restart VLC.

Under "media", select "open directory" and choose the directory you want. The playlist will display all the music files by directory and you can minimise or maximize a directory.

You can even open totally unrelated directories, even partitions apart and VLC will categorize them by folder.

See screenshots below:

[image]

[image]